# How to store time and date in plist and compare it with now time iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

I'm trying to develop am iPhone application doing the following tasks:

1. user stores his movies time and date in plist .
2. before the movie starts, e.g. 30 minutes before start, the application will give him notification

Now I'm asking for two points:

1. there is only date field on plist how we can store full time and date at once
2. how we can keep application compare the current time with movies time on plist even in background

if possible tell me with small example . ( to keep application  comparing in background )

example :

**Movies.plist** 
 - id
 - movie_name
 - showing_time

if i have record

id : 1
movie_name: Games B 2
showing_time : 2014-05-22 2:00AM

today is 21-5

i want the application send notification at : tomorrow at 1:00 AM

there is no problem with notification code  i know it's like this

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2];
    localNotification.alertBody = msg;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

the problem is how the application will send the notification in the specific time and date

for your information this things is not only for one record in plist , maybe the user will store 10 movies in different  days and time .

**another example :**

****if i open the application and i go to Save New movies i enter 3 different movies name and showing time 
and i click save
all the details will saved in Movies.Plist 
and i closed the application . now the application should give me local notification before any of Plist Movies start . 
this is whole idea  .****

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem with scheduling the notifications once your user selects the movie and time. When you schedule a local notification, the system will handle it from there. Your app does not need to be active to receive the notification. If you schedule 10 local notifications, they will appear at the fire date without you doing anything more than what your code shows. In your bold example, schedule the notifications when you save the details to Movies.plist. Make a local notification for each movie you're adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDates store the date and the time. For example, the current date and time could be represented as: `2014-05-21 17:19:13 +0000`.

As for the background process, it'll be unnecessary. When the user sets the movie time, schedule a notification for 30 minutes before the set time. There won't be any ongoing comparison, the notification will fire when the correct time is hit..

Comment: if the user sets the movie time for example = 2014-05-21 20:10:00

he is out of the application , so the application every 10 minutes  will check is there any movie after one hour if there , will show the notification , i know how to use notification but i have problem with the times and comparing only , thinks for answer but i couldn't understand what you mean . 


thanks

Comment: I'm confused by what you're asking. So you have the user's set time, but you don't have the available movies for that time? At what point do you have both the user's set time and the available movies? Once you have both, you can do your comparison and schedule notifications. Edit your original post with a more detailed step by step for intended behavior Right now I'm at: 1. User sets time, 2. User closes application, 3. Something happens, 4. A notification is displayed. I don't know what happens at step 3.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store something nor to do some background checks, if you want notify user in specific time - just use `UILocalNotification`, here's the link to Apple documentation on local notifications [UILocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: dear , if i have plist for { movies => time }

for example if i have recored 
movie name ------- time
-----------|----------
Games Bond   2014-05-22 2:00 AM


now this record already stored in plist 

i want my application before 2:00 AM will send notification . 
for example in 2014-05-22 1:00 AM i will see the notification that Games Bond Movie will start after one hour

Comment: Than just iterate over that list and create local notifications on given time(or maybe before movie starts) with movie title or other alert text.

Comment: Yes i understand the logical progress but i don't understand how we can do it with code , i have more than three controller need the notification , i mean not in one place only if possible provide me an example or tutorial  if you understand what i mean